# How to avoid the ugly empty space of the placeholder for the vertical scrollbar in QTableView?

Tags: qstandarditemmodel

In a QTableView instance, rows are variable, the row count are not fixed most of the time. In a moment, if the row count is lower than the display count of the viewport, a ugly empty-space placeholder for the vertical scroll bar will show up as in the below picture.
[image]

I tried viewportSizeHint(), maximumViewPortSize(), ... finally, a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: If there is a n-column table originally, super().__init(m,n+1) should be called. The extra empty column is  to fix the visual effect. 
The last thing to remind, just ignore this extra column. Ignore it! No need any other specific codes for it. No any bad side effects have been found until now. 
Feel free to post your reviews.

```
class KBWWTableModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: QtCore.QObject=None):
        # add a extra empty column to fix the visual effect
        # super().__init__(1, 3, parent=parent)
        super().__init__(1, 4, parent=parent)
```

[image]